# Hyperledger Fabric Multi-Org

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am following the official tutorial about Deploying a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric (multiple organizations). I was able to up the network using the provider Org1 and Org2 example. Now I want to customize the organization as my own. But upon execution of ./byfn.sh -m up -s couchdb -a command. I am getting the below error; I inspect all the yaml files but I was not able to find the possible root cause of the error. I just really need a help on this. Thank you.

```
Starting for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'couchdb',   and using Fabric CAs
Continue? [Y/n] Y
proceeding ...
LOCAL_VERSION=1.2.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.2.0
WARNING: The COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file is invalid because:
Service peer0.org2.example.com has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.
ERROR !!!! Unable to start network
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your peer-base.yaml file is not correct. One Problem is the COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME variable. If it is not set, fabric uses the folder as the network-name. But if it is not right there will be some error while bootstrapping the network. We are building a bidding network and it is called trade-network. So the example of the entry in the peer-base.yaml file is:

```
- CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
```

Before the boostrapping we define the COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME with trade-network so the network is called trade-network_basic. I'm not 100% sure but I think after (or while) bootstrapping there is a point where fabric uses the folder name anyway. So we decicded to use the folder name by default and nothing happened wrong.

The other problem could be the image entry for the peer. In our file it is:

```
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0
```

You can `docker images list` and will know which images you have, you have to use one for the peers. After the colon you can be more specific and I would suggest it.

Here is an example of our full peer-base.yaml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  peer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.0
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
      #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
```

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for the answer. I was just not able to update one of the configuration in one of the yaml file. My bad.